# Android: how do I fix CardView selection based on position passed in an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I pass data from my RecyclerView Adapter to my MainActiviy.  I also use an interface in the Adapter to capture the CardView item position in the MainActivity's onItemClick() and pass that position to a new Activity (CardViewDetails) using an intent.  Problem is the CardViewDetails loads the wrong CardView. How do I use the CardView "position" to launch the correct CardView?  What am I missing here?

```
MainActivity
...
public void passDataFromAdapter(Bundle bundle) {
    data = bundle.getString("spantimeinhours");
    data2 = bundle.getLong("timeinhours");
}

// This method works with an interface in the Adapter to capture the 
//  CardView item position.    
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position, final View view) {        

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Details.class);        
    intent.putExtra("adapterSpanTimeInHours",data);
    intent.putExtra("adapterTimeInHours",data2);
    startActivity(intent);
}

Details
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        msgFromAdapter = extras.getString("adapterSpanTimeInHours");
        msg2FromAdapter = extras.getLong("adapterTimeInHours", 0);
}     

Adapter
public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private void passDataFromAdapter(Bundle bundle) {
    if (context == null)
        return;
    if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
        activity.passDataFromAdapter(bundle); // this method must be implemented inside `MainActivity`
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you'll have to post your adapter code and how it ties into the main activity as well.

Comment: Post your adapter code here please

Comment: ok will add above.

Comment: Post your whole adapter code please.

Comment: Full adapter code added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this in your onBindViewHolder

```
 viewHolder.myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // Handles the row being clicked.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int adapterPos = itemHolder.getAdapterPosition(); // get the item position.
            if (adapterPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                    recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(adapterPos, itemHolder.itemView);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: here Myview is your view on which you want to implement onClick